# Toad Data Point crashing while launching

Tags: toad, toad-data-point

I am getting an error while launching Toad Data Point. It keeps on crashing anytime I try to open it. The error says: "***Toad encountered a serious error and must be closed. Please save your data and close the application. We apologize for the inconvenience***".

[image]

**The log error says:**

```
---------------------------------------------
NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace: 
   at Quest.Toad.ConnectionManager.ConnectMediator.IsEqual(ConnectMediator mediator, Boolean ignorePath, Boolean ignorName)
   at Quest.Toad.ConnectionManager.ConnectionHierarchy.FindExistingConnection(ConnListNode parent, ConnectMediator mediator, Boolean ignorePath)
   at Quest.Toad.ConnectionManager.ConnectionHierarchy.FindExistingConnection(ConnListNode parent, ConnectMediator mediator, Boolean ignorePath)
   at Quest.Toad.ConnectionManager.ConnectionHierarchyStorage.AddConnections(StorageItem storageItem)
   at Quest.Toad.ConnectionManager.ConnectionHierarchyStorage.AddItems(StorageItem storageItem)
   at Quest.Toad.ConnectionManager.ConnectionHierarchyStorage.AddNodeItems(Boolean notify, Boolean ignorePath, ResultSet resultSet, ConnGroupNode groupNode, XmlNode platformNode)
   at Quest.Toad.ConnectionManager.ConnectionHierarchyStorage.XmlToNodes(XmlDocument xmlDoc, ConnectionHierarchy hierarchy, Boolean notify, Boolean ignorePath)
   at Quest.Toad.ConnectionManager.ConnectionHierarchyStorage.Load(ConnectionHierarchy connectionHierarchy, XmlDocument xmlDoc, Boolean notify, Boolean ignorePath)
   at Quest.Toad.ConnectionManager.ConnectionHierarchyStorage.Load(ConnectionHierarchy connectionHierarchy, Boolean notify)
   at Quest.Toad.ConnectionManager.ConnectionHierarchy..ctor()
   at Quest.Toad.ConnectionManager.ConnectionHierarchy.get_Instance()
   at Quest.Toad.Gui.MainForm.repositoryItemCurrentConnection_CustomDisplayText(Object sender, CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem.RaiseCustomDisplayText(CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem.GetDisplayText(FormatInfo format, Object editValue)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemPopupContainerEdit.GetDisplayText(FormatInfo format, Object editValue)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.ViewInfo.TextEditViewInfo.GetDisplayText()
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.ViewInfo.BaseEditViewInfo.OnEditValueChanged()
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.ViewInfo.BaseEditViewInfo.set_EditValue(Object value)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarEditLinkViewInfo.GetEditSize(GraphicsCache cache)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarEditLinkViewInfo.CalcLinkIndent(BarIndent linkIndent)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarLinkViewInfo.CalcConstants()
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarLinkViewInfo.CalcLinkSize(GraphicsCache cache, Object sourceObject)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarControlViewInfo.CalcLinkSize(BarItemLink link, GraphicsCache cache, Object sourceObject, BarLinkViewInfo linkInfo)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarControlViewInfo.PreCalcMultiLineSize(GraphicsCache cache, Object sourceObject, Int32 AMaxBarWidth, Int32& ARestWidth)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.DockedBarControlViewInfo.PreCalcMultiLineSize(GraphicsCache cache, Object sourceObject, Int32 AMaxBarWidth, Int32& ARestWidth)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarControlViewInfo.PreCalcBarDrawInfo(GraphicsCache cache, Object sourceObject, Int32 width)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarControlViewInfo.CalcBarSize(GraphicsCache cache, Object sourceObject, Int32 width, Int32 maxHeight)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.Controls.CustomControl.CalcSize(Int32 width, Int32 maxHeight)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.BarDockControl.IsEmpty(IDockableObject dockable)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.BarDockControl.AddDockable(IDockableObject dockObject, Int32 rowIndex, Int32 colIndex, Boolean updateIndexes)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.Bar.ApplyDocking(BarDockInfo dockInfo, Boolean applyFloatingBarLocation)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.Utils.BarManagerDockingHelper.UpdateBarDocking(Boolean applyFloatingBarLocation)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.Utils.BarManagerLoadHelper.LoadCore()
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.Utils.BarManagerLoadHelper.Load()
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.BarManager.OnFormLoadComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.BarManager.OnEndInit()
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Container.ComponentEditorContainer.EndInit()
   at Quest.Toad.Gui.MainForm.InitializeComponent()
   at Quest.Toad.Gui.MainForm..ctor()
   at Quest.Toad.StartupForm.MainAppicationEntryPoint(String[] args)
   at Quest.Toad.ToadProcessEntryPoint.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by removing the connections.xml file kept at "C:\Users<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Quest Software\Toad Data Point 5.4"
It is loading now properly with no issue